# How to get the HttpServletResponse response into Spring Boot’s REST controllers?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am struggling to get `HttpServletResponse response` into Spring Boot’s REST controller. The purpose behind is that I would like to return a file stream from a REST controller.

Here is the code.

```
@Component
@Api(value = "/api/1/download", description = "act upon selected file.")
@Path("/api/1/download")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RestController
public class DownloadResource {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DownloadResource.class);

    @Autowired
    HttpServletResponse response;

    @ApiOperation(value = "Download a selected file", notes = "allows to download a selected file")
    @Path("/downloadFile")
    @POST
    @Autowired
    public void download(Object fileObject)  {
        String name = (String) ((LinkedHashMap) fileObject).get("path");
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=abcd.txt");
        try
        {
            Files.copy(Paths.get(name), response.getOutputStream());
            response.getOutputStream().flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }

}
```

Neither File is download nor it throwing an error. Please help suggest. Thank you.

Comment: Try this @ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource download(Object fileObject) { String name = (String) ((LinkedHashMap) fileObject).get("path"); 
    return new FileSystemResource(name); 
}

Comment: It isn't a spring controller it is a jersey endpoint... Those are different beasts.

Comment: @MaximTulupov Thank you. I am trying your solution and will get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try. Did I understand what you were trying to do?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class FiledownloadApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FiledownloadApplication.class, args);
    }


    @PostMapping("/downloadFile")
    public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> download(@RequestBody FileDownload fileDownload) throws IOException {
        String path = fileDownload.getPath();
        FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource(path);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(fileSystemResource, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    class FileDownload {

        String path;

        public FileDownload() {
        }

        public String getPath() {
            return path;
        }

        public void setPath(String path) {
            this.path = path;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will give that try and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it should be like this.

```
public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> download(@RequestBody FileDownload fileDownload, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException { ... }
```

And Spring will set the response object for you. What you were trying to do is to inject the bean "HttpServletResponse" which does not make much sense as it is not a bean.

Comment: Hi , I have a question here , How do we  use this HttpServletResponse object in a class which is calling this controller?

Answer (score 1):

According to this documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch15s03.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments

you can simply declare `HttpServletResponse` as an argument of your download method in arbitrary order, i.e.

```
public void download(Object fileObject, HttpServletResponse response)  {
```

or for your specific needs you can directly reference `OutputStream` i.e.

```
public void download(Object fileObject, OutputStream out)  {
```

When using either of these you should use `void` as return type of your method

Or another alternative worth a look would be to use
[StreamingResponseBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/StreamingResponseBody.html)